# Using unique session for each directory in localhost

Tags: php, session

I have several projects running on the same local server, when I run `session_start()` and `print_r($session)`, session data from any project appears.

How can I start the session without picking up session data in other directories/projects on the server?

Comment: why not just name them

Comment: Wow! Very Thanks, I hope this answer helps more people!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`session_name()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php) to create a unique name for each project. Make sure to call it before `session_start()`.